# How to match .grd data and .txt data

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a lot of data in .grd and .txt formats, for example:

```
20121201.grd
20121202.grd
..
..
..
201121231.grd
```

and also:

```
Result.2012.1201.txt
Result.2012.1202.txt

::
::
Result.2012.12.31.txt
```

I already tried to use the below command to match between the .grd data and the .txt data. I also put the .grd data and the .txt data in the same folder.

```
for n in *.txt
   do echo "processing $n"
   grdtrack "${n%.*}.txt" -G2012*.grd > "${n%.*}h.txt"
done
```

But unfortunately the command is not working.

This is the result:

```
processing Result.2012.1205.txt
grdtrack: Could not find file [2012*.grd]
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: After I check the my .txt files, the first and second line of the file is not lon and lat but pixel and line. The position of lon and lat is i third and fourth line. Can we process the data although the first and the second of .txt data is not lon and lat?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do (for example, are you trying to process files in the format 2012.mm.dd  or 2012.mmdd  ?  (You have both listed).

You can "carve up" a string in bash using {$n:x:y}  where x is the start position and y is the number of characters, so something like this [ with adjustments for your usage case ] should work:

```
for n in *.txt 
do
    echo "Processing $n"
     grdtrack $n -G{$n:0:4}{$n:5:4}.grd > {$n}h.txt
done
```

This will process the txt files and parse a parameter -G20121202.grd, redirecting output to a new text file.

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more on string manipulation in bash.

Comment: format .txt data is: pixel -- line -- lon -- lat--present -- chla -- sst. Actually .grd data is SSHA data. So I want to convert the .txt data onto: pixel -- line -- lon -- lat -- present -- chla -- sst -- ssha. Thank you.